# Do I have to make the "Login with Apple" the first option to get my iOS app approved?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, hig

Here is the [policy](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/?cid=siwa-e-en-0008#4.8) updated by Apple:

> Apps that use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook
>   Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn,
>   Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the
>   user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple
>   as an equivalent option. A user’s primary account is the account they
>   establish with your app for the purposes of identifying themselves,
>   signing in, and accessing your features and associated services.

Here is the UI Design reference:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/

I am quite new to iOS development. I've heard stories that Apple has a very strict approving-system. So my question is, do I HAVE to put the Apple Login in the first place (as `#2` and `#3` in the image below) comparing to the rest (like Facebook, Twitter)?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be sufficient to just follow the guidelines and you should be fine. They *generally* tend to be non-ambiguous.

From the [Sign in with Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/):

> **Prominently display a Sign in with Apple button**. Make a Sign in with Apple button no smaller than other sign-in buttons, and avoid making people scroll to see the button.

and

> #### Creating a Custom Sign in with Apple Button
>
> If your layout requires it, you can create a custom Sign in with Apple button for iOS, macOS, or the web. For example, if you support multiple sign-in methods, you may want to display sign-in buttons that use left-aligned logos, or that display a logo only.

and

> **Use the system font for the title — that is, Sign in with Apple, Sign up with Apple, or Continue with Apple**. To look correct, the title and button height of your custom button should use the same proportions that the system uses. Specifically, the title's font size should be 43% of the button's height — in other words, the button's height should be 233% of the title's font size, rounded to the nearest integer. Here are two examples that illustrate these proportions.

Also, you can use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) to make sure that your button appears as intended on all the supported device screen sizes.

Take your time to read thought the linked document, following the guidelines, and you should be fine.

**P.S.**: To answer your original question, *Do I have to make the “Login with Apple” the first option to get my iOS app approved?*, while Apple hasn't explicitly asked to display the **Sign in with Apple** as the first button, they have asked for a prominent placement. This could be open to interpretation and if the App Store review team feels that the placement is not *prominent* they may reject a submission on that ground.