# App submission rejected because of apple login button

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, hig

We added Sign in with Apple capability to our app, but our submission got rejected by the App Store Review team with the following message:

> We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user experience than Apple users expect:
>
> - Your app uses Sign in with Apple as a login option but does not use Sign in with Apple button design, branding and/or user interface elements appropriately as described in the Sign in With Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

A screenshot was added to the message:

[image]

The Apple logo has been downloaded from their guidelines site, so stating it doesn't use Apple button design or branding or apple user interface elements is wrong.

Why do they think this is "lower quality user experience"? Help would be greatly appreciated.

What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: Because it looks a bit cruddy - The other two icons are round, while the Sign in With Apple button is square.  The square is smaller than the circles and the Apple logo is noticeably smaller than the Facebook and Twitter logos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I have to make the "Login with Apple" the first option to get my iOS app approved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242354/do-i-have-to-make-the-login-with-apple-the-first-option-to-get-my-ios-app-appr)

Answer (score 1):

> The Apple logo has been downloaded from their guidelines site, so stating it doesn't use Apple button design or branding or apple user interface elements is wrong

Probably this specific guideline gave your app away:

From the [Sign in with Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/):

> **Prominently display a Sign in with Apple button**. Make a Sign in with Apple button no smaller than other sign-in buttons, and avoid making people scroll to see the button.

Also, while Apple hasn't explicitly asked to display the Sign in with Apple as the first button, they have asked for a prominent placement. This could be open to interpretation, and if the App Store review team feels that the placement is not prominent they may reject a submission on that ground.

Additionally, the Sign in with Apple button appears smaller in size compared to the buttons for the other login options.

It would also be advisable to go through the linked Sign in with Apple Human Interface Guidelines document and make your best attempt at interpreting it and adhering to the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much regarding Apple specifications for applications features and/or logins, however, I have seen a lot of login with Apple buttons, and many of them look similar to this:

[image: Sign in With Apple]

Although you may have included the Apple logo, the companies brand toward this specific type of login service may be different from their overall branding as an Apple. I would suggest using similar designs as on the image I posted.

For large corporations, branding doesn't just mean the logo, it means you identify the logo and there is a feeling you get when you see something commonly associated with their company. No offense but pressing on the logo that you have posted does not provide a user with the feeling that is commonly associated with "Apple" which is usually minimalistic, but with a "Brand name" or "Identifier" along with it. In this case the Apple logo with a few words saying Sign in With Apple. Changing to this format may help